# How to find a range of objects in containers based on more than one parameter

Tags: c++

I am looking for the best way to extract objects from a large collection based on their position from *two* sorted parameters.

Example:

```
struct Object{
    Time start;
    Time end;
    //... data
};
```

Now, for any time `t` I want to *quickly* find all objects that "exist" within this time, i.e. `t` is between the objects' `start` and `end` values.

The approach I have thought of is to use:

```
std::multimap<Time, object*> objectsOrderedByStart;
std::multimap<Time, object*> objectsOrderedByEnd;
```

(`multimap` since there may be many objects with the same `Time` values, which are the sorted keys)

Every time I create an `Object` I add it to each `multimap` which automatically places the object in a sorted list for `start` and `end`.

I then "query" for my valid objects for time `t` by looking for all objects in `objectsOrderedByStart` where `t>Time` and objects in `objectsOrderedByEnd` where `t<End`, and then taking only those that are in both result sets. But this seems inefficient and the only technique I can think of to find the union is by going through one result set one-by-one and looking to see if that object is in the other result set.

However I suspect this is not the most efficient method. I could iterate by skipping over the elements when iterating each `multimap`, rather than one-by-one iteration, then fall back if I've gone too far and iterate one-by-one from the last skipping point. Alternately I could retain just one `multimap` and then peer inside each `object` to look at its `end` time.

But I suspect there is a better way to organize this data and find those in the range that interest me?

Comment: @n.m. i'm curious, how did you find that other question? it's not one of the "related" questions that appear, and searching didn't turn that up for me. Of course that question is not c++ specific, or not tagged as such, so perhaps part of the issue.

Comment: It is a well known problem and a relevant google search (*time interval search* I think) brings that other question up pretty high in the results.

Comment: @n.m. so far the method I've most been able to wrap my head around is the Augmented Interval Tree http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two manually-sorted arrays instead of two multimaps, and then use `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound`, or hand-coded binary search, to search in them.

Comment: I think custom bsp is the way to go, in particular, an Augmented Interval Tree seems to be a good choice here

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at [Boost.ICL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html)